# Difference between poll_s and ep_poll WCHAN in ps output

Tags: linux, process, ps

When I issue `ps -elf|grep python` for example on my system, I see these:

```
1 S 1000      6020  6008  0  80   0 -  9914 poll_s Jul12 ?        00:00:01     python manage.py run_gunicorn -t 3600 -w 8 -b 127.0.0.1:8000
0 S 1000     22496 22491  0  80   0 - 10477 ep_pol 12:32 ?        00:00:10     /var/lib/mywebapp/env/bin/python /var/lib/mywebapp/env/bin/pserve development.ini
```

What is the difference between `poll_s` and `ep_pol`?

Answer (score 8):

To display a bit more of the `WCHAN` function name, you can use e.g.:

```
ps -e -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm
```

This will show you the two functions are `ep_poll` and `poll_schedule_timeout`.

The first is in `fs/eventpoll.c` in the kernel, and is related to [`epoll`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html) facility, specifically to the [`epoll_wait`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) system call.
The other is in `fs/select.c` and will be used both for the "plain" [`poll`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/poll.2.html) system call, and for [`select`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html).

So they are both "waiting for something I/O-related to happen" wait states, but for different system facilities.

Comment: This answer assumes the question was about Linux...

Comment: I think the output format given for `ps -elf` guarantees Linux.